# Parse.com iOS [PFObject saveAll] / [PFObject saveAllInBackground] Memory Allocation Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

thanks in advance. Whenever I call [PFObject saveAll] or [PFObject saveAllInBackground] the memory that is allocated to this process fails to deallocate upon completion of the task. As a result, if this method were to be called repeatedly the app would crash from a lack of available memory. I'm testing this on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.3 and using Xcode 6.2 as well as ARC. I'm also using the latest Parse SDK for iOS, although this problem persists through older SDKs as well.

**EDIT**

I submitted a bug report to Parse a few weeks ago. They've assigned people to investigate it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/349439421926879/

Source code for the bug: https://github.com/EpsApps/Parse-PFObject-saveAll-Memory-Bug

Evidence that the bug exists: https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2087-6/10935993_1605305476371209_1781513233_n.png

Comment: Please post code and evidence that memory actually leaks.

Comment: Are you using `PFRelation` anywhere?

Comment: @random No, I'm not using PFRelation anywhere.

Comment: @danh the memory section of the debug navigator hovers around 230 MB when I save roughly 90 PFObjects. If I break the saves up into smaller groups of 10 barely any substantial memory is allocated.

Comment: Do you retain these objects anywhere else?

Comment: @Andy No. I've submitted a bug report to Parse and they've acknowledged that there is an issue. I'm not sure if this bug affects all devices because I am only testing on the iPhone 5. The person I was in communication with at Parse was testing on the 5s and experienced the same problems. Also, it should be noted that this bug only arises for me when doing a save all on objects that contain pointers to other PFObjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a workaround to this bug. When adding an object as a pointer, do a simple query for this object rather than reusing the same object that was pulled via a more complicated query.

For instance, this will result in a big memory leak when including the "bigObject" as a pointer for a big save all:

```
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Object"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object.objectId];

// Don't include an array of pointers like this
[query includeKey:@"objectArray1"];
[query includeKey:@"objectArray2"];

PFObject* bigObject = [query getFirstObject];
```

But this won't:

```
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Object"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object.objectId];

PFObject* smallObject = [query getFirstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's been different for me every run, sometimes the memory footprint does completely go away. Check out the following graphic.

Most of the time there seems to be some sort of residual though, I agree.

[image]
<sub>(source: [derrrick.com](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/parse_memory.png))</sub>

Comment: Interesting. How many objects are you saving at a time? I've noticed that if you save fewer objects at once, for instance under 10, there is barely any residual. When I start to save 25+ it becomes really obvious that there is a lot of used memory that isn't being deallocated.

Comment: Also, if I save an object with lots of **new** pointers to other objects the same issue arises.

Comment: if this is going to be a huge issue in production for you, then i recommend you reach out to the folks at Parse

Comment: Yep, exactly, in the process of compiling a sample project for them now